# Ignore cell formatting in Google sheets calculations

Tags: validation, google-sheets, formatting

OK, I've spent a long time trying to get something that seems simple working.

I'm using Google sheets. I have a requirement to allow users to enter decimal only (i.e. numbers and a single '.' only)

The formatting on the cells can vary (Accounting/Number/Text/Financial).

I'm using a REGEXMATCH which does what I need it to - the full calc is this:`=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B3), "^\d+\.?\d*$")`

It all works, except on Accounting format - when cells are formatted as accounting, it displays a £ up front (£    123.4).

The VALUE of the cell in this case is still 123.4. However, the REGEXMATCH calculation doesn't seem to think so. Any cells with a valid value in but that are formatted as accounting, fail the validation.

I've attached an example sheet. I tried converting the value to number using `TO_PURE_NUMBER` first but of course that means that it's perfectly valid for someone to enter a £, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Any thoughts welcome. Can I ignore the formatting somehow?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xv82O-7LcxeeU6Keb2qygyyeL5XVYzqnZYnwsUaHy5k/edit?usp=sharing

Tried `=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B3), "^\d+\.?\d*$")` - it worked except on accounting cells

Answer (score 0):

What about a validation that checks if it's a number?, No matter the formatting, if it's a number you'll be able to calculate on it.

```
=ISNUMBER(B3)
```

**UPDATE:**

What about:

```
=LEN(TO_TEXT(B3))=LEN(VALUE(B3))
```

If there's an additional symbol even if it's just shown because of format it will be detected:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately ISNUMBER allows users to enter the £ sign themselves and it won't fail validation. I could script a solution but it seems like overkill.

Comment: Check the update! PS: it will work better with conditional formatting rather than with Data Validation

Comment: (With Data Validation it will work better if you have previously formatted everything as number only)